# SOAP client TypeScript

Tags: php, node.js, typescript, api, soap

I'm using this lib: https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap, to get data from an API. I have a file caled apiDecoder.ts with the following code:

```
     class NuSoapClient{

        public GetNuSoapInfo():string{

            var soap = require('soap')
            var url  = "https://my.url.com/consultNFSe/server.php?wsdl"
            var args = {token. :"mysecrettoken",
                        doc    : "000000000",
                        number : "000000000"
                       }

            soap.CreateClient(url, function(err, client){
                client.MyFunction(args, function(err, result){
                    console.log(result);
                });
            });
            return
        }
     }

var nf = new NuSoapClient()
nf.GetNuSoapInfo()
console.log(nf)
```

I get the following error when I compile the code:

```
  " SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:895:18)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11 "
```

PS: I was coding the same function in PHP (OO too), there is a missing argument that I didn't get the way to use in TypeScript, the "consultaNFSe" on $res variable. It defines who I'm calling in the API. Here's the working PHP code with Nusoap lib:

```
$client     = new nusoap_client('https://my.url.com/consultNFSe/server.php?wsdl'); 
$parameters =  array('token'=> $results->token,
                          'cnpj'=> $results->cnpj,
                         'nrNota'=> $results->nota);

$res      = $client->call('consultaNFSe', $parameters);
$contents = file_get_contents("data.php");
$arr      = json_decode($res, true);
```

Any thoughts? I'm stuck at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sugest you to call all libraries outside class scope, ex:

```
const soap = require('soap')

class Examp {}
```

I'm not pretty sure but I think that soap.CreateClient require another not optional parameter (options). So, will be:

```
 soap.CreateClient(url, {}, function(err, client){ //here second parameter
                if (err) throw(err);
                client.MyFunction(args, function(err, result){
                    console.log(result);
                });
            });
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: I've used the way you said, but now I get the error: "Cannot read property 'MyFunction' of undefined".

Comment: Be sure that yo have installed soap library correctly, also you can use lexical import: import * as soap from 'soap';

Comment: @ViniciusMocci you need to check your wsdl. `MyFunction` must be declared in it